# Regarding WPF & attractive UI

Tags: wpf, user-interface

i am learning WPF. i saw a very beautiful application called Blu Twitter client developed with WPF. their UI is really glossy. 
[image]

can anyone give me some tips that how could i create this type of glossy UI with WPF. what i need to do.......need concept.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get Expression Blend (it's free if you are student), it is fairly easy to create some fancy UIs with it - it has really nice graphical designer.

Here is tutorial, which explains how to make such glossy control: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mgrayson/archive/2007/02/16/creating-a-glass-button-the-complete-tutorial.aspx . This covers basics of how to compose the graphics from gradients and similar graphical primitives and how to make it react on mouse actions.

But be warned: it takes some graphical talent to actually create original graphics! The design above is clearly a work of graphical artist, even though I don't like it - I hate the preudo-3D effect on the navigation buttons, window state controls and message boxes. And similar window transparency tends to be counter-productive.

EDIT:

Note that Expression Blend is since the 2012 release part of the Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Or in addition to mzabsky's suggestion, if you want a more programming approach, the key here is to restyle some of the existing WPF controls. The UI in your picture is not too complex, a main list, a toolbar perhaps at the bottom, a decorator in the upper left corner, some grid/panel layout, nothing unusual, but they are heavily re-styled. Other than that, a couple well-chosen colors with transparency (maybe some color animations for hovering too).

As a starting point, you should get yourself familiar with control restyling in WPF.